# How to save cookies and use them later?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I log into the site https://dmarket.com. I want to save cookies and use later. In order not to visit the site next time.

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        string steamguard = textBox3.Text;

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();                       
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live%2Fauth%2Fv1%2Fcallback%2Fsteam%2F901e7d34-06c1-44b0-82b4-2f982c058361");

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamAccountName\"]")).SendKeys(login);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamPassword\"]")).SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"imageLogin\"]")).Click();

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"twofactorcode_entry\"]")).SendKeys(steamguard);            
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"login_twofactorauth_buttonset_entercode\"]/div[1]")).Click();
                                                   
        var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
        driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookies);           
    }
```

But an error occurs: Error CS1503 Argument 1: Unable to convert from "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection <OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie>" to "OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie". Maybe I'm doing something wrong. And maybe it should have been done differently.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience dealing high level with cookies will fail you , to master and get root of the problem my way :

1. Get Cookie manager extension for Firefox or whatever browser you are using.
2. see how many cookies key/value you are getting after logging.
3. install fiddler sniffer and see how many of them sent in request after login when browsing the website.
4. extract that cookies and inject them in HttpClient or similar class and track the requests with fiddler if succeeded or not .
5. once socket request succeeded , i add the same headers and cookies to selenium request, and continue doing my selenium stuff.

maybe longer approach but always worked with me , let me show you an example with instagram login :

```
 var ig_did = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("ig_did");
        var sessionid = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("sessionid");
        var mid = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("mid");
        var ig_nrcb = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("ig_nrcb");
        var rur = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("rur");
        var csrftoken = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("csrftoken");
        var ds_user_id = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("ds_user_id");

        string ig_did_value = ig_did.ToString().Substring(0, ig_did.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("ig_did=", "");
        string sessionid_value = sessionid.ToString().Substring(0, sessionid.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("sessionid=", "");
        string mid_value = mid.ToString().Substring(0, mid.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("mid=", "");
        string ig_nrcb_value = ig_nrcb.ToString().Substring(0, ig_nrcb.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("ig_nrcb=", "");
        string rur_value = rur.ToString().Substring(0, rur.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("rur=", "");
        string ds_user_id_value = ds_user_id.ToString().Substring(0, ds_user_id.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("ds_user_id=", "");
        string csrftoken_value = csrftoken.ToString().Substring(0, csrftoken.ToString().IndexOf(";")).Replace("csrftoken=", "");
```

Then inject them to HttpClient and sniff them with fiddler :

```
     

               var baseAddress = new Uri("https://www.instagram.com");
                    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                    {
                        CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
                        Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888", false),
                        UseProxy = true,
                        AllowAutoRedirect = true
                    })



                    using (httpclient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
                    {


                
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken_value);
                        
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "My_Instagram_URL");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-IG-App-ID", Ig_app_Id_value);
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
                        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");


                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("ig_did", ig_did_value));
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("mid", mid_value));
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("ig_nrcb", ig_nrcb_value));
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("csrftoken", csrftoken_value));
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("sessionid", sessionid_value));
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new System.Net.Cookie("rur", rur_value));

                        string url = "My_Instagram_URL";

                        var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(url);

                     

                      


                    }
```

As said it's looks long approach but this is will always work.

Good Luck.

Comment: When I do this, it gives me null. var sessionID = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("sessionID");

Comment: and when check manually do you see cookie value for the key "sessionID" after logged ? , if yes make selenium wait before var sessionID = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("sessionID");